# Which is faster for information retrieval in js? Object vs Calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, object

Which is faster to retrieve information from, an object or a simple calculation?
Is there a notable difference between them?

Context:

- Web development
- Using js and/or jQuery
- up to hundreds of items affected on a page

Here is a sample of the object I would retrieve information from:

```
var pModel = {
    1 : {sire: 3, dam: 4, herdList: settings.sireList},
    2 : {sire: 5, dam: 6, herdList: settings.damList},
    3 : {sire: 7, dam: 8, herdList: settings.sireList},
    4 : {sire: 9, dam: 10, herdList: settings.damList},
    5 : {sire: 11, dam: 12, herdList: settings.sireList},
    6 : {sire: 13, dam: 14, herdList: settings.damList}
};
```

After I wrote the code, I noticed the mathematical pattern inherent in the data:

```
// Where x is a number
pModel[x].sire == 2x+1;
pModel[x].dam == 2x+2;
(x%2=0) ? settings.damList : settings.sireList;
```

There are obvious future proofing advantages to using math, but speed is a major consideration here.

Comment: Then, the pattern is gone...

Comment: How is the pattern gone?

Comment: Unless you're referring to the object having an inherent beginning and end. That's where the math is better for future proofing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for math that simple, it turns out math is faster:

http://jsperf.com/object-vs-calc

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know that site existed. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Math should be faster, if you know the algorithm, you don't even need the object literal.  The object literal is immediately interpreted before you even need it, while math only takes up what processor/time you need.

With an object literal, the time it takes to do the lookup is likely more then the mathematical calculation, as it relies on a mathematical calculation + additional overhead related to traversing the object.

Go with math.

Comment: as long as your math is as simple as the above one, yes - go math. If you start finding loops and conditionals, then pre-calculation can help you out. And if in doubt, benchmark it.

Comment: +1 for the useful explanation.